# Issue with posting to a Lambda functions URL

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

When I try to post to my lambda function url I get a very generic 502 internal server error.

I deployed the function with serverless and when I invoke it locally as well as just invoke the function with serverless from my terminal in vscode I get a successful return.

Comment: 502 internal server error means you need to go look at the server logs (AWS Lambda logs) to see what the actual issue is.

Comment: Are you using correct payload when executing a POST call?

Comment: Im pretty new to aws so honestly I dont know if I am sending the correct payload. I was just trying to  provide it a basic json object. 
{ "ID": "12345"} @rotimislaw

Comment: I tried checking cloudwatch for the logs, but they never show up. So I dont know what the actual error is. I should be hitting the function because I copied the link from AWS, so I dont think I am hitting the wrong URL. @MarkB

Comment: @AlanShipley you should work out why CloudWatch Logs don't show up or you're going to continue to struggle with Lambda. Ensure your function's invocation role has the relevant [permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/access-logs.html).

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% sure what ended up resolving the issue, but I think I was added more than one post method in the API gateway and calling the wrong one. I  ran SLS remove and then SLS deploy and once done I was able to get the api calls to return the 200 status

Answer (score 0):

Are you using API Gateway? I recommend looking at the AWS example photo asset management app that demonstrates how to invoke Lambda functions from a client app using API Gateway.

[image]

In addition, there is an AWS CDK script you can use to set up backend resources. Once done, you can run the app and look at the code.

See this doc topic in the [AWS COde library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html):

[Create a photo asset management application that lets users manage photos using labels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_PAM_java_2_topic.html)